# Matching multiple NSEvents in NSEventMask

Tags: swift, macos, nsevent

Below statement handles any left clicks done in my macOS app. I wish to capture all clicks (left, right, middle, wheel etc). I know I can add a monitor for each one of them but is there a way to combine all of those events in one eventmask ?

```
NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents(matching: .leftMouseDown , handler: {
            (mouseEvent:NSEvent?) in .....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mask` parameter is of type [`NSEventMask`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nseventmask). `NSEventMask` conforms to [`OptionSet`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/optionset). So, you can use set syntax to represent multiple options:

```
NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents(matching: [.leftMouseDown, .rightMouseDown, .otherMouseDown] , handler: {
            (mouseEvent:NSEvent?) in .....
```